# nano cursor traversal over certain text scrambles the underlying letters in gentoo

Tags: gentoo, nano

I have the following line in ~/.bashrc

```
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"
```

traversing the cursor over the line with `nano`, changes the letters into

```
[ -x /usrr/bin/lsssspipe && && eva$( "$(SHEbiL=/bin/ssh lessp   pe)"
```

This doesn't happen in ubuntu

In Gentoo

```
# eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"
-su: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
```

In Ubuntu it gives no output

In Gentoo

```
$ lesspipe
Usage: lesspipe <file>
```

In Ubuntu

```
$ lesspipe
export LESSOPEN="| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s";
export LESSCLOSE="/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s";
```

Comment: I think you have two questions here. One is related to your terminal/shell setup when moving your cursor around. Another is `lesspipe`. It looks like the `lesspipe` script that Gentoo installs is not intended to be used that way. If you look at the header, it says you can put something like `export LESSOPEN="|lesspipe %s"`, though this should already be done for you by `/etc/env.d/70less`, so you should just remove it from your `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: Does your issue with `nano` happen when you use a virtual text terminal to use `nano` (e.g., ctrl+alt+f1)? Does it happen when using `xterm`? What terminal are you using and what is `TERM` set to? (`echo ${TERM}`).

Comment: both `$TERM = linux` or `$TERM = xterm-256`